# Access to my localhost from computers on the same network

Tags: vpn, remote, ping

- I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 15.10
- I am connected to the VPN of my office
- I have Apache installed

When I try to access to my localhost via the IP address of my computer, from another computer on the network, it just hangs.

I can't `ping` my computer either.

However, if I connect my computer to the LAN, then it responds to ping and also shows localhost.

Is there anything I should do to make this work? It's weird to me since I've set up Vagrant boxes and accessed to localhost via the ipaddress as long as the host computer was connected to the VPN.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry about that; let me try to explain better. This fresh install only has Ubuntu and Apache. If I go to 127.0.0.1 from my computer, it displays the Apache welcome page. If I ping any of the IPs of the computers connected to the VPN, I get proper response. 

However, if someone else pings my computer, it hangs, no response, and same thing if they try to access to my localhost via typing my ip on the browser.

Comment: How do I know the ip addresses configured? I already explained what I am doing, just in case.

Comment: I would guess that it's an issue with the VPN (Firewall ?), not with Ubuntu.